# Get Nanosecond Unix Timestamp in Kernel Module

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, unix-timestamp, kernel-module

I am pretty new to kernel module programming. Therefore I compiled an easy hello world tutorial module. However, I failed at an easy task while modifying the hello world:

How do I get a unix timestamp with nanosecond granularity?
I expected the following code to work, but it returns a value, that is not the nanosecond unix timestamp:

```
unsigned long ns_time;

struct timespec ts;
getnstimeofday(&ts);

ns_time = 1000000000 * ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec;
```

Comment: Isn't `getnstimeofday` supposed to get the time of day?.. You will get the same time of day in 24 hours, 48 hours, 72 hours and so on.. http://man.cx/getnstimeofday(9) You aren't getting a universal time / unix timestamp with that.. This will get you a timestamp in seconds:   time_t seconds; time(&seconds); I don't know if there's a way to get a unix timestamp in C (in milliseconds or nanoseconds) that i'd recommend.. May i ask why you need nanosecond precision in your timestamp?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the nanosecond resolution, because I printk() events that occur more often, than every second (at least 5 times a second). I really wonder, that I am the first that has this question^^

Comment: If you obtain the unix timestamp in seconds (with time(&seconds)), multiply with 1,000,000,000 and add it with ts.tv_nsec from your code, doesn't that result in a correct unix timestamp in nanoseconds? It would mean 2 method calls per event (getnstimeofday(&ts) and time(&seconds)) and it would maybe even add some error to your measurement but i guess you would get the desired effect..

Comment: It would be great if you could provide an example, I can accept as the right answer ;)